# how to render a react component for every item in JSON file?

Tags: reactjs, components, rendering, state

i want to build workout app so i created a JSON file that has an "exerciseName" and "discription" (i am just playing with react)

1st i created a component called "ExerciseCard"

```
  import React from 'react'

function ExerciceCard(props) {

        return(
            <h1>this is the exercie {props.exerciceName}</h1>
        )
}


export default ExerciceCard
```

and then i created a page called CreateNewWorkout

```
import React from 'react'
import ExerciseCard from '../component/ExerciseCard'

class CreateNewWorkout extends React.Component {
    state = {
        exercises : []
    }

    async    componentDidMount() {

        let response  = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/calisthenics-exercices")
        const data =  await response.json()
//i wanted to loop throgh the array of and push the exerciceName to the exercise state array
        for (let i = 0; i <data.lenght; i++) {
            this.setState({exercices : [...this.state.exercises, data[i].exeriseName]})
        }

    }
    render() {
        return(
            <>
            <ExerciseCard exerciceName = {this.state.exercice} ></ExerciseCard>
            </>
        )
    }

}

export default CreateNewWorkout
```

currently i have two "exercises" in the JSON file, and i want to know how to render `ExerciseCard` component two time (in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's doing like following

```
<div>
  {dataAsArray.map(val, i) => (
    <div key={i}>{val}</div>
  )}
</div>
```

So, you need

```
<div>
 {this.state.exercice.map(ex, i) => (
   <ExerciseCard exerciceName={ex} key={i} />
 )}
</div>
```

Note: Your data flow in the component is wrong - not for production usage.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple that u cant set State multiple times in a loop instead first push all the elements in a list and then finally set the state as below

```
async    componentDidMount() {
        let response  = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/calisthenics-exercices");
        const data =  await response.json();
const updatedState = [...this.state.exercise]
data.forEach( item => updateState.push(item))
setState({exercises : updatedState});
```

and then inorder to render this

```
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.exercise.map(item => <ExerciseCard exerciseName ={item} />)}
            <div/>
        )
    }
```

Comment: It will produce a warning "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique “key” prop..." Add a prop 'key' in your solution to avoid